# SharedPreferences not retrieving int data

Tags: android, listview, int, sharedpreferences

I have a saved preference that is suppose to record the number of times the button is pressed.  When the user closes out of the actvity and comes back, the number of times the button has been pressed previously should be retrieved and the user should be able to continue increasing the value.  No errors are comming up and I do not know what I am missing

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);


        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(Inbox.this, R.id.listView1, fetch);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        LoadInt();

        dede = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.days);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                day++;
                dede.setText("Test" + dayCounter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listViewContent();
                SaveInt("key", day);
            }
        });

    }
```

LoadInt is called right before my onCreate is called.

SaveInt is called inside of my onclicklistener.

```
public void SaveInt(String key, int value) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

public void LoadInt() {
        SharedPreferences lp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        dayCounter = lp.getInt("key", day);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a case issue.
While you are saving, you used "Key"

```
SaveInt("Key", day);
```

while getting you used "key"

```
lp.getInt("key", day);
```

Comment: Thanks for the Catch, fixed it but still having same issue.

Comment: are you sure that you are correctly setting the stored value to your textView? You must set dayCounter. Share its code.

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot, I've been working on this project for a few hours, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have a capital 'K' on the key when your trying to save and retrieving with a lowercase 'k'

Comment: Thanks for the Catch, fixed it but still having same issue.

Comment: What is this 'Day' value? it's supposed to be a default value?

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter that  your Key is not equal key ( lower and upper case :-) ) ?

Comment: Thanks for the Catch, fixed it but still having same issue.

Comment: I agree & I'll improve ansewers in the future :-)